# Best formular logic

Tags: forms, logic

I have a formular for customers who want to update their postal address.

Doing so, they might want to have an updated document (let's say an ID card) being sent per post.

I'm wondering what is the best way to show this.

The logic is:

1. customer enters his/her new data (address...)
2. we ask them if they want the new ID card sent
3. if yes, it could be sent to their new address, or to a different address

At the moment, I'm struggling between making it as simple as possible (less clicks) and as logic as possible.

So I have the question with a select:
Want a new ID card sent? with the following options:

- (please choose)
- no
- yes at my new address (they gave it before)
- yes at a different address (some more fields show up)

I'm not sure that the select is the best option. Also, they don't have to get their new ID card sent, so does it even make sense for the customer to have to answer no... they could just ignore the field, unless we make the field compulsory.

We could also ask them before: yes or no? Then if yes, to whom. But that would be extra clicks.

Comment: Can you clarify the 3rd option in your second example ("yes at my new address (they gave it before)") we know this address, yes?

Comment: Yes we do know it

Comment: If they are updating their address, why would someone enter another address to which they may have their ID card sent?

Comment: "Do you wish a new ID card sent? If so, do you wish it sent to an address other than the new address already provided?" If yes, yes, open appropriate fields labeled "Send ID card to: ...".

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simpler interaction than those suggested already:

For the existing/different address, I'd just provide a set of editable ship-to fields populated with the current address. If the user wants the ID sent to a different address they can edit it there.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFhwfm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Let me differentiate two kinds of users for this scenario.

*UserA*: **User who wants the ID**.

*UserB*: **User who doesn't want the ID**.

---

Adding a mandatory field:

+. Benefits UserA as he won't miss the option.

+. Benefits UserB as he will be aware of the option(he might have not payed attention to,otherwise)

-. Is more inconvenient for UserB as he has to perform one more action (he wouldn't need).

---

In your case you might want to **evaluate the number of users of each type you have**.

- If the majority of your users are A, then add a mandatory field.
- If the majority of your users are B, then evaluate: Are you really interested in UsersA (minority) having the ID even if that means it might make UsersB (majority) do an extra click?

  - Yes: Add a mandatory field
  - No: Don't add a mandatory field

---

About how to do this field:

If not mandatory I would do a checkbox that when checked displays the address fields to complete. Like in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h9Lcuau3/1/show/).

If mandatory a dropdown with ---/yes/no which then opens new fields; or like the one you are proposing with ---/no/yes at my new address/yes at a different address.

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, I would create a mandatory radio button group, similar to this:

Want a new ID sent?*

- No thanks
- Yes, to my new address
- Yes, to another address

If the user selects to another address, show another field for the mailing address that is only required when "Yes, to another address" is selected.

The benefit of the radio group vs a select group is that users can see all of the choices before clicking.